# added events are not showing in calendar app in android

Tags: android, calendar

I am using calender provider to insertEvent in google calender . The problem is I am getting the Query result as Uri without any exception and event Id also . But the Event i am adding is not showing in calender app.Can anyone Help me . And i also wanted to set reminder for my event . Below is the code i am using to add event .

```
     public void addNewEvent() {
     long startMillis = 0;
     long endMillis = 0;
     Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
     beginTime.set(2016, 4, 1, 7, 30);
     Log.e("startTime",new SimpleDateFormat("MM:dd:yyyy").format(beginTime.getTimeInMillis()));
     startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
     Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
     endTime.set(2016, 4, 1, 8, 56);
     endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
     // Insert Event
     Log.e("endTime",new SimpleDateFormat("MM:dd:yyyy").format(endTime.getTimeInMillis()));
     ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Going for a ride");
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Event desc");
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 39);
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,"Malta");
     Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
     // Retrieve ID for new event
     long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
     setReminder(cr, eventID, 100);
     Log.e("eventId",eventID+"");
}

 public void setReminder(ContentResolver cr, long eventID, int timeBefore) {
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, timeBefore);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
            Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, values);
            Cursor c = CalendarContract.Reminders.query(cr, eventID,
                    new String[]{CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES});
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                Log.e("Reminder Uri",uri.toString());
                Log.e("","calendar"
                        + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES)));
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

above code helps in adding events to phone calendar only.if you want to add events to google calendar then you have to use google calendar api. when adding events to phone calendar i have set calendar id to "1".

Comment: phone calendar is google calendar isn't it? Because it is binded with my all google account .

Comment: if you turn off the sync then events in phone calendar will not be shown in google calendar....so instead you can directly add events to google calendar using google calendar api

Comment: even i am facing the same issue... i am using same code as mention in the question...to add event and set reminder...

My event is getting added in google calendar (on website) but when i sync it on the phone...it doesnt shows... 

Even Reminder aren't working properly...on the phone... 
website gets alerts of that event though

Comment: @ADM you got any solution for this?

Comment: This is way too back when i asked this question . I don't remember the solution i have used . Have you tried setting calendar ID to 1 ?